# Group by period.apply() in xts

Tags: r, xts

Hi i have an xts object with 4 variables (2 id vars and 2 measures):

```
> head(mi_xts)

                     squareId country     smsIN     smsOUT
2013-12-01 00:00:00     9999      39 0.4953734 0.93504713
2013-12-01 00:10:00     9999      39 0.1879042 0.50057622
2013-12-01 00:20:00     9996      39 0.5272736 0.25643745
2013-12-01 00:30:00     9996      39 0.0965593 0.25249854
2013-12-01 00:40:00     9999      39 1.2104980 0.49123277
2013-12-01 00:50:00     9999      39 0.4756599 0.09913715
```

i'd like to use a period.apply that returns the mean of smsIN and smsOUT group by squareId (i don't care about country) per days.
I just wrote this code:

```
days <- endpoints(mi_xts, on = "days")
mi_xts.1d<- period.apply(mi_xts, INDEX = days, FUN = mean)
```

but obviously i get only 1 row result:

```
                    squareId country     smsIN    smsOUT
2013-12-01 23:50:00   9995.5      39 0.8418086 0.6644908
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `split` by `"squareId"`, aggregate using `apply.daily`, then `rbind` everything back together.

```
s <- split(mi_xts, mi_xts$squareId)
a <- lapply(s, function(x) apply.daily(x, mean))
r <- do.call(rbind, a)
```

Comment: ok but i obtain also squareId processed values like 9996.160, 9995.500. I tried to force that field as character but when i slit i get "Error in endpoints(x, on = f, k = k) : unsupported "on" argument"

Comment: @andriatz: You can't make one column character. xts objects are a matrix with a time attribute, and you can't mix types in a matrix like you can with a data.frame. I don't get odd `squareId` values when I use your example data.  Maybe add some more rows to the object in your question (use `dput()` please).

Comment: i'm actually working on a large dataset (400 mb). squareId is an integer Id column wich has range of 1 to 1000. I need to find daily average for each sqaureId.

Comment: @andriatz: I understand the data is large. But I don't understand how you can split data into chunks by integer and get non-integer mean values in the output.

Comment: right.  i applied another function 'to.period()', so this is the reason why i obtain non integer values. So, is that split/lapply workaround i useful only with mean funcion?

Comment: @andriatz: `to.period()` creates OHLC data. Surely that's not what you want...?  You used `period.apply()` in your question. `apply.daily()` is just a wrapper around `period.apply()`, so there's no reason it should cause integer values.  The `split()`/`lapply()`/`rbind()` solution will work for any function that takes a matrix and returns a scalar or 1-row matrix with the same number of columns.

Comment: ok, apply.daily() works fine for that purpose. I think that the to.period problem will take place in another question. Thank you!