# Average of month's data (jan-dec) in xts objects

Tags: r, split, lapply, xts, do.call

I have this large **xts**, aggregated monthly with **apply.monthly** function.

```
2011-07-31 269.8
2011-08-31 251.0
2011-09-30 201.8
2011-10-31 95.8
2011-11-30 NA
2011-12-31 49.3
2012-01-31 77.1
...
```

What I want is to calculate the average of Jan-Dec months for all the period. Something like this, but in **xts** form:

```
01 541.8
02 23.0
03 34.8
04 12.8
05 21.8
06 44.8
07 22.8
08 55.0
09 287.8
10 15.8
11 113
12 419.3
```

I want to avoid using **dplyr** functions like **group_by**. I think there must be a solution using **split** and **lapply** / **do.call**

I tried spliting the xts in years

```
xtsobject <- split(xtsobject, f = "years")
```

and then I dont know how to use properly the **lapply** function in order to calculate the 12 averages (Jan-Dec) of all the period.
This question
[Group by period.apply() in xts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208443/group-by-period-apply-in-xts)
is similar, but in my xts I dont have/want a new column, I think it can be done using the xts index.

Comment: Can you share a subset of your data using `dput` ?

Comment: You mean like this ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJ8t7xUVnbB83rCAugivYLW8Esptc5s2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input data `x`, shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use`aggregate.zoo` like this:

```
ag <- aggregate(x, cycle(as.yearmon(time(x))), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
ag
```

giving the following zoo series:

```
1   77.1
7  269.8
8  251.0
9  201.8
10  95.8
11   NaN
12  49.3
```

We could plot it like this:

```
plot(ag, type = "h")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "2011-07-31 269.8
2011-08-31 251.0
2011-09-30 201.8
2011-10-31 95.8
2011-11-30 NA
2011-12-31 49.3
2012-01-31 77.1"

library(xts)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines)
x <- as.xts(z)
```

Comment: This solution has a problem with the NA's. where can I use a **na.rm=T**-like option ?

Comment: Yes, that is supported.  Have modified.

Comment: As a further comment I want to say that this aggregate.zoo works well even with multiple column xts objects, its returns the monthly average of **each column separately**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `base::months` function to extract the month before calculating the mean:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, base::months(index(x))), mean, na.rm=TRUE))
```

output:

```
              [,1]
April     165.1600
August    290.2444
December  106.8200
February   82.6300
January    62.9100
July      264.9889
June      246.4889
March     100.5500
May       246.3333
November  116.6400
October   151.3667
September 158.5667
```

Comment: It works thanks !. Is there a way to sort the output in Jan-Dec Order?

Comment: Should be something like ans[match(month.name, rownames(ans)),]

Comment: Using lubridate::month instead base::months works fine. **do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, lubridate::month(index(x))), mean, na.rm=TRUE))**

Answer (score 2):

It seems the index is a number and not a `POSIXct` object. You can convert it and use `format` to extract months and use it in `tapply` :

```
tapply(xtsobject[, 1], format(as.POSIXct(zoo::index(xtsobject), 
                          origin = '1970-01-01'), '%m'), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```